# How can I directly access the next column in my treeview to insert data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, peewee

I have set up a treeview to display data from my sqlite db. I am able to fill the first column with a query and now I need to fill the other columns with different queries.

```
    # Top Container
    top_frame = ttk.Frame()
    top_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
    # create a treeview with dual scrollbars
    list_header = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=list_header, show="headings")
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",
                        command=self.tree.yview)
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal",
                        command=self.tree.xview)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,
                        xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
    self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W), in_=top_frame)
    vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, S), in_=top_frame)
    hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W), in_=top_frame)

    # Display the headers
    for col in list_header:
        self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(), command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
        # adjust the column's width to the header string
        self.tree.column(col)

    # Display the data
    query = ProjectNumber.select()

    for item in query:
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item.project_num)
```

[how can i access the next column and fill it with a separate query?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMq5m.png)

Answer (score 0):

if I've understand, below you can see a working example of what you want to do.

The example is write in oo approach.

After launch the script click on Load button, you will see the treeview populate with

data that simulate a recordset ,list of a tuple. After try to click on a item of the

treeview and see what happens. I've add even click and double click event callback.

The data represent Italian pasta dishes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        f = tk.Frame()

        tk.Label(f, text = "Buon Appetito").pack()
        cols = (["#0",'','w',False,200,200],
                 ["#1",'','w',True,0,0],)

        self.Pasta = self.get_tree(f, cols, show="tree")
        self.Pasta.show="tree"
        self.Pasta.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.Pasta.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.on_selected)
        self.Pasta.bind("<Double-1>", self.on_double_click)

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Load", command=self.set_values).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def set_values(self,):

        #.insert(parent, index, iid=None, **kw)
        rs = [(0,'Spaghetti'),(1,'Rigatoni'),(2,'Pennette')]

        for i in rs:
            #print(i)
            pasta = self.Pasta.insert("", i[0], text=i[1], values=(i[0],'pasta'))
            rs_dishes = self.load_dishes(i[0])
            if rs_dishes is not None:
                for dish in rs_dishes:
                    #print(dish)
                    wards = self.Pasta.insert(pasta, dish[0],text=dish[1], values=(dish[0],'dishes'))


    def load_dishes(self, i):

        rs = [(0,'Spaghetti aglio e olio'),
              (1,'Rigatoni alla matriciana'),
              (1,'Rigatoni al pesto'),
              (1,'Rigatoni alla norma'),
              (2,'Pennette al pesto'),
              (2,'Pennette alla wodka'),
              (2,'Pennette al tartufo'),
              (0,'Spaghetti allo scoglio'),
              (0,'Spaghetti al pesto'),
              (0,'Spaghetti alla carbonara'),
              (0,'Spaghetti alla puttanesca')]

        r = [x for x in rs if x[0] == i]

        return r

    def on_selected(self, evt=None):

        selected_item = self.Pasta.focus()

        d = self.Pasta.item(selected_item)

        if d['values']:
            if d['values'][1]=='dishes':

                pk = d['values'][0]

                print("pk: {}".format(pk))


    def on_double_click(self, evt=None):

        if self.Pasta.focus():
            item_iid = self.Pasta.selection()    
            pk = self.Pasta.item(self.Pasta.focus())['text']

            print(item_iid, pk)


    def get_tree(self,container, cols, size=None, show=None):

        headers = []

        for col in cols:
            headers.append(col[1])
        del headers[0]

        if show is not None:
            w = ttk.Treeview(container,show=show)
        else:
            w = ttk.Treeview(container,)

        w['columns']=headers

        for col in cols:
            w.heading(col[0], text=col[1], anchor=col[2],)
            w.column(col[0], anchor=col[2], stretch=col[3],minwidth=col[4], width=col[5])

        sb = ttk.Scrollbar(container)
        sb.configure(command=w.yview)
        w.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

        w.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand =1)
        sb.pack(fill=tk.Y, expand=1)

        return w

    def on_close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I found how to access the next column by changing self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item.project_num) to self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(item.project_num, item.project_name)), someone similar to what you had. I like the callback you added I was going to look into that next. Thank you